# .Net Detecting Application Launch

Tags: c#, wmi

I am currently trying to monitor applications being launched and closed, below is my current code but whenever it is executed i receive an access denied error, any in depth ideas or reasons to why this is happening would be much appreciated

```
    class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("root\\CIMV2");
                scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = true;
                try
                    {
                        ManagementEventWatcher startWatch = new ManagementEventWatcher(
                            new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace"));
                        startWatch.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(startWatch_EventArrived);
                        startWatch.Start();
                        ManagementEventWatcher stopWatch = new ManagementEventWatcher(
                        new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace"));
                        stopWatch.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(stopWatch_EventArrived);
                        stopWatch.Start();
                        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
                        while (!Console.KeyAvailable) System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
                        startWatch.Stop();
                        stopWatch.Stop();
                    }
                catch (ManagementException e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e);
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }
            }
            static void stopWatch_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e) 
{
        Console.WriteLine("Process stopped: {0}", e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessName"].Value);
      }

      static void startWatch_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e) 
{
        Console.WriteLine("Process started: {0}", e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessName"].Value);
      }
            }
```

Comment: `i receive an access denied error`: where ?

Comment: Sorry, this is within Visual studio, so running the console application outside of debugging is fine, when trying to debug i receive the exception at startWatch.Start();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this error is occurring because you not running your application in elevated mode. If you are running your application from Visual Studio then, run Visual Studio in elevated mode, else run your application exe in elevated mode:

Right click on VS exe/shortcut and select "Run as Administrator" option.

If you are directly running your application exe, then right click on your application exe and select "Run as Administrator"

Comment: And that would be my fix... -.- I am domain admin as well as local admin, that's very annoying but good to know going forward, many thanks